# How to change the width and height of an element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, slider

so this slider changes the width of the iframe and I tried to add another slider to change the height of the iframe but I didn't know what the JavaScript should be for that. So my question is how can we add another slider that can change the height of the iframe, what should the JavaScript be? This is the HTML and the JS:

```js
let slider = document.querySelector('[type=range]')
let div = document.querySelector('#myIframe')

slider.addEventListener('input', e => {
  div.style.width = e.target.value + 'px'
})
```

```html
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>

<input type="range" min="240" max="1024" value="240" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: There's no sign of the other slider in the question.

Comment: What have you tried? The pattern you need to follow is right there, you just need to adjust `width` -> `height`. That being said, adding a draggable handle in the bottom right of the iframe container would be a much more user-friendly solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a CSS alternative

```css
iframe {
  height: 140px;
  width: 240px;
  resize: both
}
```

```html
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
```

Alternative with a bigger thumb.

note that is the DIV I resize and the iframe size follows the div size. The span can contain any character or an image and the position needs to follow the resize handle

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 145px;
  width: 245px;
  resize: both;
  overflow:hidden;
}

iframe {
  height: 98%;
  width: 98%;
}

.handle::after {
  display: block-inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  right: -2px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 2em;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: gray;
  content: "⇲";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="handle"></span>
  <iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

But if you insist, just add one for the height.

I suggest to delegate from a static container

For fun I added the css so the resize by dragging the corner will update the sliders too

```js
const iFrame = document.querySelector('#myIframe');

const sliders = document.getElementById('sliders');
const w = document.getElementById('w');
const h = document.getElementById('h');
sliders.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('[type=range]');
  if (!tgt) return; // not a slider
  iFrame.style.width = w.value + 'px'
  iFrame.style.height = h.value + 'px'
})

iFrame.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
   w.value =  parseInt(iFrame.style.width)
   h.value =  parseInt(iFrame.style.height)
})
```

```css
iframe {
  height: 140px;
  width: 240px;
  resize: both
}
```

```html
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>

<div id="sliders">
  <label>width: <input type="range" id="w" min="240" max="1024" value="240" style="width:100%" /></label>
  <label>height: <input type="range" id="h" min="140" max="1024" value="140" style="width:100%" /></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! The first one doesn't even need JavaScript, this is awesome. I liked it. Thanks a lot for all your help, sir. I appreciate it.

Comment: How do you customize that resize handle? It is too small and very dificult to move around. does it have a specific name so I can style it? If so, what are the properties? I looked for that on google but found nothing.

Comment: See update. I now wrap the iframe in a div and have a span that contains the resize "icon", you can use an image or another character

Comment: What am I missing? The added character and/or the image has abolutely no effect on resizing the iframe, not even in your snippet. I still have to use that small dot. Does doing it on a phone have to do with this?

Comment: So it does work if the iFrame is slightly smaller than the DIV. I am not sure why it changed between me uploading and you testing. it. Try again

Comment: thanks a lot. Could you please answer the latest question on my profile if I'm not bothering you?

Comment: What question, where?

Comment: This is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77980021/how-to-change-the-width-of-the-content-of-an-iframe-and-not-the-width-of-the-ifr

Comment: I am not sure if the pictures would explain it but I'll try to explain in words: the width of the iframe should be fixed and the slider should change the width of the content of the iframe instead. That's it. As simple as that. Please let me know if there is anything unclear.

Comment: It is just that the width slider should change the width of the content of the iframe. What else has to be known? Let me know please so I can try to explain.

Comment: Please post two images. One initial view and one where the sliders have been used

Comment: Also let's stop discussing this in this question

Answer (score 0):

You can add id for every slider, then query the elements:

```js
let widthSlider = document.querySelector('#widthSlider')
let heightSlider = document.querySelector('#heightSlider')
let iframe = document.querySelector('#myIframe')

widthSlider.addEventListener('input', e => {
  iframe.style.width = e.target.value + 'px'
})
heightSlider.addEventListener('input', e => {
  iframe.style.height = e.target.value + 'px'
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>
<body>

  <iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
  <input id="widthSlider" type="range" min="240" max="1024" value="240" style="width:100%">
  <input id="heightSlider" type="range" min="240" max="1024" value="240" style="width:100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sliderWidth = document.getElementById('setWidth');
let sliderHeight = document.getElementById('setHeight');
let div = document.querySelector('#myIframe');

sliderWidth.addEventListener('input', e => {
  div.style.width = e.target.value + 'px';
})
sliderHeight.addEventListener('input', e => {
  div.style.height = e.target.value + 'px';
})
```

```html
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>

<input type="range" id="setWidth" min="240" max="1024" value="240" style="width:100%">
<input type="range" id="setHeight" min="240" max="1024" value="240" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: Not really any improvement on already posted answers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).