# How to change the width of the content of an iframe and not the width of the iframe itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, slider

I have these two sliders that change the width and the height of the iframe, however, I don't want the width slider to change the width of the iframe itself, but rather the width of the content of the iframe. So the result should be like switching between mobile mode and desktop mode using that slider (which means that the full width of the content should always be visible within the full width of the iframe) and the width of the iframe itself should be fixed. How can this be done, please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <style>
  
    iframe {
      width: 240px;
      height: 240px;
    }
    
    #sliders {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0%;
      left: 0%;
      right: 0%;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 8px;
      border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    }
  </style>
  
</head>

<body>
  
  <div style="overflow-x: scroll">
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="index.html"></iframe>
  </div>
  
  <div id="sliders">
    <label>width: <input type="range" id="w" min="240" max="1024" value="240" style="width:97%" /></label>
    <label>height: <input type="range" id="h" min="240" max="1024" value="240" style="width:97%" /></label>
  </div>
  
  <script>
    const iFrame = document.querySelector('#myIframe');

const sliders = document.getElementById('sliders');
const w = document.getElementById('w');
const h = document.getElementById('h');
sliders.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('[type=range]');
  if (!tgt) return; // not a slider
  iFrame.style.width = w.value + 'px'
  iFrame.style.height = h.value + 'px'
})
      
  </script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is the content `same-origin` or `cross-domain`?

Comment: I'm still not sure of the difference between the two but let's say that I still have my website on a local host and want to test its responsiveness.

Comment: _"and want to test its responsiveness"_ - then you _should_ probably rather be changing the width of the iframe itself. Because otherwise, any media queries that are based on the window width, are hardly going to work properly.

Comment: I would not test it within an iframe. Use the dev console for the first tests. But be aware that no test is a 100% accurate test compared to testing it on actual devices. Good developers have different devices to actually test RWD and UI/UX. The main issue where an iframe will fail to test accurately are mobile devices that use a DPR setting.

Comment: got it. Ok thanks to you guys for the information.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to include a description of your goal or desired end result, without referring to implementation details like iframes and sliders. It’s unclear what you really want to be able to do.

Answer (score 1):

An iframe is a "hole" in a page that other web pages can display. The content of the iframe in no way constitutes or becomes part of the home page.

As others have mentioned, your options are:

- Provide appropriate CSS for the data to be loaded into the iframe
- If the data in the iframe has the same name as parent, then the DOM
  of the document in the iframe You can access it from the parent.